# Automatically load next image from array everytime user enters website

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

So this code selects random image whenever a person loads my website, how can I change the code so that images are selected sequentially from first to last everytime a person loads the website and then again resets to first image when the counter reaches the end?
P.s- The code works fine on hosting server, here it gives an error i don't know why.

```js
window.onload = choosePic;

var myPix = new Array("https://i.imgur.com/LHtVLbh.jpg", "https://i.imgur.com/2YHazkp.png", "https://i.imgur.com/Uscmgqx.jpg");

function choosePic() {
     var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPix.length);
     document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Random Image</title>
     <script src="thumb.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="images/spacer.gif" id="myPicture" alt="some image">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. You need to change the id of the image tag to `myPicture`, since you use `getElementById`; 2. If I have 3 images, you want to display the first one when I enter, then if I refresh the page to show the 2nd one again, then after another refresh the 3rd one and after to go back to the 1st one?

Comment: Use localstorage.

Comment: Just changed the ID to myPicture, it works now. Question still remains, how can I change it to select next picture.
@Adi Yes exactly 1st image then 2nd then 3rd then again 1st but it should be on the website so suppose user1 visits it loads image 1, user2 visits it loads image2, user1 again visits it loads image3 and likewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to achieve this. When the user enters the website, you can do something like:

```
var pictureIndex = localstorage.getItem("pictureIndex");
```

But since it may be the user's first visit, it would be better to have:

```
var pictureIndex = localstorage.getItem("pictureIndex") || 0;
```

Then, you just increment the pictureIndex and perform a modulo operation (for the case when this is the last image)

```
pictureIndex = (pictureIndex + 1) % myPix.length;
```

To save this index, you can use

`localStorage.setItem('pictureIndex', pictureIndex)`;

Next time when the user refreshes the page (or comes back), he will get the next picture in your array.

The final code should look like this:

```js
window.onload = choosePic;

var myPix = new Array("https://i.imgur.com/LHtVLbh.jpg", "https://i.imgur.com/2YHazkp.png", "https://i.imgur.com/Uscmgqx.jpg");

function choosePic() {
     var pictureIndex = window.localStorage.getItem("pictureIndex") || 0;
     pictureIndex = (pictureIndex + 1) % myPix.length;

     window.localStorage.setItem("pictureIndex", pictureIndex);
     document.getElementById("imgid").innerHTML = pictureIndex;
     document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[pictureIndex];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Random Image</title>
     <script src="thumb.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  Press "Run" multiple times to cycle through the images.
  Currently showing: <span id="imgid"></span>
 <img src="images/spacer.gif" id="myPicture" alt="some image">
</body>
</html>
```

*Note that the above code might not work here (but you can test it locally) due to some security restrictions from jsfiddle. A working version can be accessed >[here](https://jsfiddle.net/adrianpop/2w36jzpy/)<*

Comment: Just implemented your code and it selects 1st image and the directly the last image.
I used var pictureIndex = localstorage.getItem("pictureIndex");

Comment: Look at the code in the fiddle at the end (https://jsfiddle.net/adrianpop/2w36jzpy/7/); I added some more photos and it works. I also added a counter to see the progress.

Comment: This works but it restarts from image 1 on every new session, I want it to be global if last request was image 2, next request should be image 3 for any user who visits it next.

Comment: If you want it to be for *every user* who visits the websites, it cannot be done with `localstorage` and you need some internal counter. Basically you need to keep a counter in a database where the website is stored and update every time a user enters the website.

I thought (as the other people who answered here) that it should be a per-user-behaviour, not a global one.

Comment: I say that it can't be done globally using just javascript because the javascript code is loaded and executed individually by every browser. Any variables declared live only in that instance and can not communicate with other instances without some real-time connections or updates.

Comment: It can not be implemented globally whether  we speak about javascript, php or python. When the user accesses the website, a bundle (a copy of the code) is sent to its browser. Another user in the other part of the world can't really know the value of another user's counter without some external communication or notification mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

```
function choosePic() {
        var local_item = 0;
        if(localStorage.getItem('pic_key')){
            local_item = parseInt(intvlocalStorage.getItem('pic_key'));
        }
        if(local_item >= myPix.length){
            local_item = 0;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('pic_key', local_item + 1);

        document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[local_item];
    }
```

You can use [LocalStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp) to achieve this. When the user enters the website, you can store the key and increment it.

Comment: The last line, `document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[local_item];` is never going to be executed since above is a return statement.

Comment: It says unreachable document after return.
Also this is how I want "user1 visits it loads image 1, user2 visits it loads image2, user1 again visits it loads image3 and likewise."

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Localstorage but after pasting your code beneath the array it doesn't load any image, Do I have to replace something here? @JestinSebastian

Answer (score 0):

Use local storage to save the data you need [e.g. visited = 3(3rd time the same person visited your website)]

Your js code can be implemented like this:

```
window.onload = choosePic;

var myPix = new Array("https://i.imgur.com/LHtVLbh.jpg", "https://i.imgur.com/2YHazkp.png", "https://i.imgur.com/Uscmgqx.jpg");

function choosePic() {
     if (localStorage.getItem('visited') == null)
     {
         document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[0];
         localStorage.setItem('visited', 1);
     }
     else if (localStorage.getItem('visited') >= myPix.length)
     {
         localStorage.setItem('visited', 0);
         document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[localStorage.getItem('visited')];

     }
     else
     {
         document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[localStorage.getItem('visited')];
         localStorage.setItem('visited', localStorage.getItem('visited') + 1);
     }
}
```

Comment: After 3rd refresh images stop showing. Please note images sequence should be global.

Comment: @Chaila You're right. I made a mistake into the "else if" which the counter were not getting reset in max count. It should work now.